# Script continues running on Ctrl + C after upgrading to Django 1.4

Tags: django, django-admin

I updated version of Django from 1.3.1 to 1.4 using `sudo pip install django --upgrade`. Now when I do Ctrl + C in one of my projects to kill the script in midway, it continues running the on going process and throws errors later.

I suppose I need to do some changes in settings.py to migrate the project to 1.4 or is it the intended behaviour in Django version 1.4?

Comment: there [are some changes that'll need some attention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-4) but ctrl+c still should shut down the dev server in 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any changes to Django in this regard but you might wanna try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>break</kbd>

Comment: It might be related to WSGI application object that is used in 1.4 for development server. Ctrl + Z did stop the script but re-starting server shows "Error: That port is already in use." Break key is not there on my Dell Laptop and thus couldn't try that.